# Virtual Machine joined to Domain Services not appearing in Active Directory Devices blade

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

I have set up an Azure Active Directory Domain Service which is successfully synchronising with Azure Active Directory.

Creating a Virtual Machine and joining the domain works sucesffully.  VM is in a separate VNET with peering.  It is possible to login to the Virtual Machine with domain accounts.

However, in the 'Devices' blade in Azure Active Directory, the Virtual Machine is not shown.

Are there any obvious things to check?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing the same thing, any Linux VM I create in Azure Portal doesn't show in the device pane of AAD, even though I am able to login to it using my AAD credentials with Virtual Machine User Login role.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to get a device identity in your Azure Active Directory:

- Azure AD registration
- Azure AD join Hybrid
- Azure AD join

If you want the Devices to add automatically after they join the domain, you need to implement **Azure AD join Hybrid**

You can have a solution in this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/369993/azure-ad-domain-services-and-azure-ad-hybrid-join.html)

---

Learn more about [Azure AD registered devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-register)

Learn more about [Azure AD joined devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join)

Learn more about [hybrid Azure AD joined devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join-hybrid)